# How can I change this file to only be the lens flare shaders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, lately, I've found that I love the look of lens flares in shaders, but, all the shaders with them also have shadows and stuff like that. I was wondering how to get only lens flares in Docteurdreads shaders, henceforth reducing lag drastically. I basically want to know what I could delete out of this zip file to have only the lens flares. [Here is the shaders zip file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/j69ycr09md82wna/DocteurDread%27s+Shaders+v02+-+Lite.zip).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a quick look at the code, it may be that if lens flare is your requirement you only need the files called:

- final.fsh
- final.vsh

Try this out and tell me what happens!

if this fails, it is possible that these may also be required:

- composite1.fsh
- composite1.vsh

Comment: Ah! Only finals blacken the screen, and composit1s show white. Add the composits, and it works. Thanks.